# Azure Container Instance Timeout Connecting to Azure SQL Database via Private Endpoint

Tags: azure, networking, terraform, architecture, containers

I'm having issues with an Azure Container Instance (ACI) timing out when trying to connect to an Azure SQL database through a Private Endpoint. My setup, all provisioned with Terraform, is as follows:

Database

```
resource "azurerm_sql_server" "azure_sql_server" {
  name                         = "azure-sql-server"
  resource_group_name          = data.azurerm_resource_group.arc_resource_group.name
  location                      = data.azurerm_resource_group.arc_resource_group.location
  administrator_login          = var.administrator_login
  administrator_login_password = var.administrator_login_password
  version                       = "12.0"
}

resource "azurerm_sql_database" "azure_sql_database" {
  name                = "database"
  server_name         = azurerm_sql_server.arc_azure_sql_server.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.arc_resource_group.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.arc_resource_group.location
}
```

Container Instance

```
resource "azurerm_container_group" "nginx_container" {
  name                = "nginx-container-group"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.arc_resource_group.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.arc_resource_group.location
  ip_address_type     = "Private"
  os_type             = "Linux"
  subnet_ids          = [azurerm_subnet.subnet_b.id]

  container {
    name   = "nginx-container"
    image  = "${var.acr_repository}.azurecr.io/docker_image:latest"
    cpu    = "0.5"
    memory = "1.5"

    environment_variables = {
        "DB_HOST" = format("%s.database.windows.net", azurerm_sql_server.arc_azure_sql_server.name)
    }
    
    ports {
      port     = 80
      protocol = "TCP"
    }
  }
}
```

Virtual network

```
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "existing_vnet" {
  name                = "vnet-uks-dev"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.arc_resource_group.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet_a" {
  name                 = "sql-sn"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.arc_resource_group.name
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.existing_vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.2.1.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet_b" {
  name                 = "aci-sn"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.arc_resource_group.name
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.existing_vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.2.2.0/24"]
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Sql"]
  delegation {
    name = "aci"
    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action"]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet_c" {
  name                 = "private-link-sn"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.arc_resource_group.name
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.existing_vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.2.3.0/24"]
}
```

DNS and private endpoint

```
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "sql_private_dns_zone" {
  name                = "privatelink.database.windows.net"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.arc_resource_group.name
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "vnet_link" {
  name                  = "vnet-link-to-private-dns"
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.arc_resource_group.name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.sql_private_dns_zone.name
  virtual_network_id    = data.azurerm_virtual_network.existing_vnet.id
}

resource "azurerm_sql_virtual_network_rule" "allow_aci_subnet" {
  name                = "AllowACISubnet"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.arc_resource_group.name
  server_name         = azurerm_sql_server.arc_azure_sql_server.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.subnet_b.id
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "database_private_endpoint" {
  name                = "pe-database"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.arc_resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.arc_resource_group.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.subnet_c.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "psc-sql"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_sql_server.arc_azure_sql_server.id
    subresource_names             = ["sqlServer"]
  }

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = "default"
    private_dns_zone_ids = [azurerm_private_dns_zone.sql_private_dns_zone.id]
  }
}
```

Given this setup, my application within the ACI is experiencing timeouts when attempting to write to the Azure SQL database. What could be causing this, and how can I successfully establish the connection between the ACI and SQL database over the private endpoint?

I have constructed this with 3 subnets as private endpoints and container instances must have dedicated subnets and will not accommodate additional resources.

I have confirmed the database connection strings are correct. I have confirmed the server is deploying with azure-sql-server.database.windows.net as its server name.

Comment: There are various reasons why this may not be working. I would triage with below steps::
1) try connecting to the console of ACI & run curl of SQL endpoint with verbose, this should give you whether it's resolved to a private/public IP & also check if ports are opened
2) Check NSGs of sql subnet if there are inbound rules actively blocking the ports
3) Do you have custom dns resolver? If yes, the resolver must have the sql private dns zone configured otherwise A records won't be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to check Azure Container Instance Timeout Connecting to Azure SQL Database via Private Endpoint Issue which in general was caused by multiple factors.

I agreed with @harshavmb on the concerns he mentioned which were the factors causing the issue you're facing.

The issue with your Azure Container Instance (ACI) timing out when connecting to the Azure SQL database could be due to a few different factors.

- Ensure that the Network Security Groups (NSGs) associated with your subnets or the virtual network are not blocking traffic between the ACI and the Azure SQL database.
- Double-check the configuration of the private endpoint and ensure it's correctly linked to the Azure SQL Server.
- Since you are using a private endpoint, make sure that the DNS resolution for your SQL Server is correctly configured and that the ACI can resolve the private IP of the SQL Server.
- You have configured service endpoints for Microsoft.Sql on `subnet_b`, but your private endpoint is in `subnet_c`. Ensure that the service endpoints are correctly set up to allow traffic to the SQL Server & Also Check if there are any firewall rules on the Azure SQL Server that might be blocking the traffic.

I tried a demo configuration which helps you troubleshoot the blocker you're facing.

**My Demo Configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "Demorg-vk"
  location = "West US"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "vksb-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example_sql" {
  name                 = "vksb-sql-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example_aci" {
  name                 = "vksb-aci-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
  delegation {
    name = "aci"
    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action"]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example_private_endpoint" {
  name                 = "vksb-private-endpoint-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.3.0/24"]
}


resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "example" {
  name                         = "vksb-sql-server"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                     = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "sqladminvk"
  administrator_login_password = "Intel@1901"
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}


resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "example" {
  name                = "privatelink.database.windows.net"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "example" {
  name                  = "vksb-vnet-link"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.example.id
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "example" {
  name                = "vksb-private-endpoint"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.example_private_endpoint.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "vksb-sql-connection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_mssql_server.example.id
    subresource_names              = ["sqlServer"]
    is_manual_connection           = false
  }

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = "default"
    private_dns_zone_ids = [azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.id]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_container_group" "example" {
  name                = "vksb-container-group"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  os_type             = "Linux"
  ip_address_type     = "Private"
  subnet_ids          = [azurerm_subnet.example_aci.id]

  container {
    name   = "example-container"
    image  = "nginx:latest"
    cpu    = "0.5"
    memory = "1.5"

    ports {
      port     = 80
      protocol = "TCP"
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]